# Is it necessary to convert database of mp3's to ogg and wave to use html audio?

Tags: html, audio

I have thousands of mp3 files in a database and a website that lets people listen to them. I'm using a flash player but want to move to html5 audio player. Does this mean that I need to make ogg and wave versions of all my audio files? What is a good approach to making these files more accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes you need to support multiple formats.  (Assuming you care about decent browser support.)

If you are lacking disk space, don't get a lot of traffic, and don't mind some delay before the data gets to the user, you can convert these on the fly.  Just write some code so that on request, it checks the conversion cache to see if you have already converted the file.  If not, convert it on the fly (with something like FFMPEG) and write the data to disk at the same time you are writing it to the client.

As Imre pointed out, browser support is changing all the time.  [Look up what codecs are supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html5_audio) from time to time.

Comment: The wikipedia page on [html5 audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html5_audio) shows what browsers support what formats.

"...for a website to guarantee HTML5 audio for all users, it has to make two formats available, often Vorbis, as used on Wikimedia sites, and MP3 or AAC."

Comment: @ImreKerr, Yes, and that browser support is changing all the time.  The point is that you need to support multiple formats, and my answer explains an option for doing that.